# init tab function when ng-repeat completed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

i have a tab function in rootScope that work with jQuery. i don't know it is true in rootScope or No. it get html and show or hide tab-content like any tab plugin. but in this case i write myself tab function.

but i can't match it with angular when data fetched from server.

```
$rootScope.tab = function () {
    $('[data-tabindex]').each(function () {
        console.log('tab');
        var index = $(this).attr('data-tabindex');
        $('[data-tabindex="' + index + '"] [data-tabc]').hide();
        $('[data-tabindex="' + index + '"] .tab-title  [data-tab]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                var i = $(this).attr('data-tab');
                $('[data-tabindex="' + index + '"] [data-tabc="' + i + '"]').fadeIn();
                return false;
            } else {
                var i = 1;
                $('[data-tabindex="' + index + '"] [data-tabc="' + i + '"]').fadeIn();
                $('[data-tabindex="' + index + '"] [data-tab="' + i + '"]').addClass('active');
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

and this is html structure

```
<div data-tabindex="tab" class="s-tab">
    <div class="tab-title">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="category in search.categories" data-tab="{{$index+1}}" >
               {{ category.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="t1" class="tabs active" data-tabc="1">
            11111111111111111111111
            <em>more</em>
        </div>
        <div id="t2" class="tabs" data-tabc="2">
            222222222222222222222222222222
            <em>more</em>
        </div>
        <div id="t3" class="tabs" data-tabc="3">
            33333333333333333333333333333333
            <em>more</em>
        </div>
  </div>
```

so i want initialize tab() function when categories fetch from server and end in ng-repeat to work correctly tab() function.
now it was not correct state and html doesn't become tab

if it work with write directive or else, please example for me